# How does Python determine the current time zone?

Tags: python, datetime, configuration, timezone

Python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) claims:

> If optional argument tz is None or not specified, the timestamp is converted to the platform’s local date and time, and the returned datetime object is naive.

So if you call this and the documentation is true, you should get the time in your system's time zone:

```py
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
```

On Linux, there are two ways to set the time zone: Either via the `TZ` environment variable, or the symlink `/etc/localtime`.

In a Docker container, the `TZ` environment variable is blank, and the localtime symlink looks like this:

```
# ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 May 11  2021 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC
```

There is also a file called `/etc/timezone` that contains `Etc/UTC`, but that file isn't mentioned in `tzset(3)`, which describes how Libc handles time zone configuration.

So this means the "platform’s local date and time" should be in UTC.
Naturally, the `date` command gives the time in UTC:

```
# date
Fri Mar 11 10:18:52 UTC 2022
#
```

But, if I start up Python 3.7.10, it seems there's another way to determine the time zone, because Python somehow decides that the "platform's local date and time" is in the Pacific time zone:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
'2022-03-11T02:18:52.183474'
```

So obviously the documentation is incorrect. Python does not use the system time zone. It has some other way of deciding what time zone to be in. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

> What is going on here?

Scrying [`datetime` source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/datetime.py) gives

```
@classmethod
def now(cls, tz=None):
    "Construct a datetime from time.time() and optional time zone info."
    t = _time.time()
    return cls.fromtimestamp(t, tz)
```

thus clearly `datetime.datetime.now` behavior depends on `time.time` function, so I guess answer is somewhere inside [`time` source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/timemodule.c) but at it is not `python` language I will let determining that to users better understanding language in which `time` module is implemented.

Comment: time.time() returns a UNIX timestamp, and UNIX timestamps are always in UTC. The time zone is applied by `cls.fromtimestamp(t, tz)`, with some special behavior occurring if `tz` is equal to `None`. In newer versions of Python, `datetime.datetime.now` is a builtin function.